# Showing all elements from a list

Tags: graphics

I have a list with graphics. Some of elements in the list are None type, how can I display all elements from that list on one picture?

```
miastaPolozenie={{69, 94}, {16, 77}, {32, 11}, {24, 20}, {34, 53}}
counter=1   
grafiki=Table[None, {i, 1, liczbaMiast*liczbaMiast}]
polaczone={{1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}}
For[i = 1, i < liczbaMiast, i++,
    For[j = 1, j < liczbaMiast, j++; counter++,
        If[polaczone[[i, j]] == 1, 
         grafiki[[counter]] = 
         Graphics[Line[{miastaPolozenie[[i]], miastaPolozenie[[j]]}]]]]]
```

I want to show all elements from 'grafiki'. I hope this is enough, names are not in English, if you need more information, let me know.

Comment: Can you give us bit of your code so we know what you are looking at?

Comment: Please edit the question and make sure it's self-contained (don't post code in comments). See here for guidelines: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/12

Comment: Sorry, deleted comment and edited the post.

Comment: This example is neither minimal, nor complete. Please show a complete minimal example. You may also be interested in reading about [better alternatives to `For`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/12), `Nothing` and `DeleteCases` (as a last resort to remove any `None`s).

Comment: But maybe you just want `SimpleGraph[AdjacencyGraph[polaczone], 
 VertexCoordinates -> miastaPolozenie]`

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was looking for. Is it possible to make dots a little bigger?

Comment: What version of Mathematica do you have? 12.0 or earlier?

Comment: I'm using 11.2.0.0 version.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are trying to visualize a graph based on an adjacency matrix.

The simplest way to merely visualize it is

```
GraphPlot[polaczone, VertexCoordinates -> miastaPolozenie, VertexSize -> 0.2]
```

If you want to manipulate the graph, build a [`Graph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html).

```
AdjacencyGraph[polaczone, VertexCoordinates -> miastaPolozenie]
```

You can remove self-loops with [`SimpleGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SimpleGraph.html).